# How do I assign a legend to some data within a for loop in Python?

Tags: python, plot, legend

I have some Python code which plots a figure. The figure contains 5 curves. Each curve is made up of 5 points. I want to label these curves using a legend.

Lets say the 5 curves have the following marker, colour and label designations:

```
markers = ['o','s','p','h','d']
colours = ['b','g','r','y','k']
labels   = ['A','B','C','D','E']
```

Just for clarity the first curve will be made up of 5 "o" points, the points will be blue and will be labelled as "A".

My data is a list of lists like so:

```
curve1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
curve2 = [2,3,4,5,6]
curve3 = [3,4,5,6,7]
curve4 = [4,5,6,7,8]
curve5 = [5,6,7,8,9]
xaxis  = [1,2,3,4,5]

data = [curve1,curve2,curve3,curve4,curve5]
```

Now I plot the 5 curves like so:

```
for j in range(len(xaxis)):
   for i in range(len(xaxis)):
      pylab.plot(xaxis,data[i],color=colours[i],marker=markers[i],label=labels[i])

pylab.legend(loc=0)
pylab.show()
```

Note there is a for loop inside a for loop which causes the legend to print out each label 5 times. How can I get around this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add a custom label to each:

```
for i,curve in enumerate(data):
   pylab.plot(xaxis,curve,color=colours[i],marker=markers[i],label=labels[i])

pylab.legend(loc=0)
pylab.show()
```

This should give:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I forgot to mention that the for loop is inside a for loop. Please see the problem again. I made some changes.

Comment: Why are you plotting the same lines on top of each other 5 times? Is that intentional, or do you want different markers for each point in the line?

Comment: I had the for-loop embedded in another for-loop as I had to set some constraints on the initial lists. I won't go into the details here. But I worked around it using your advice. Works a charm. Cheers.